# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mailmerge'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, modulenotfounderror, mailmerge

The following code brings the above error when executed in VS Code **only**

```
from __future__ import print_function
from mailmerge import MailMerge
```

When I run in in command prompt, however, it performs fine. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling docx-mailmerge numerous times, as well as updating pip. Any ideas as to why this is only happening in VS Code?

Comment: Your VS code project is likely configured with a different Python interpreter/venv from the one you use in the command prompt.

Comment: Choose the right interpreter(`Ctrl+Shift+P-->Python: Select Interpreter`) and use Python extension(`Run Python FIle`) to execute your code

Comment: @JialeDu I got stuck at the step of "use Python extension to execute your code". What do you mean by this? If it is saved as a python file, will it not automatically run with the python extension?

Comment: @blhsing how can I go about fixing this?

Comment: How do you execute code now? Have you installed the [**Python**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extension? I mean executing the code using the `Run Python FIle` option and not any other option that comes with any other extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your VS Code may be configured with the wrong Python environment, or you may have forgotten to activate your virtual environment, if you have one.

Comment: How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: Open VS Code & open any Python file, and look in the bottom right for a Python and curly braces icon. On the right should be your Python version & possibly venv. Click on it, and you should have an option to configure your Python interpreter. If you have a virtual environment that you are using somewhere, type in that path, or select the global interpreter if that's what you were using in Command Prompt.